# npm build is not picking up latest changes

Tags: npm-build

`npm run build` does not seem to pick up latest changes while `npm start` shows the changes. I am trying a few code changes in a few .ts files including change of a URL which should be immediately reflected. Upon running npm start I see the updated URL but npm run build seems to pick up some old code version still. Can someone please help or point to the problem?

I have tried going through the stackoverflow posts on the same subject and tried removing node_modules and package-lock.json but no luck. Is there any other thing I can do it to force npm build to pick up the changes? The only way I can be sure that npm build is picking it up is if the URL change is reflected clearly.

Comment: have to tried removing the build folder and then running `npm run build`

Comment: i tried removing the build folder and rebuilding again, but same result. The indicator was a mistyped URL that should have reflected whereas it is still showing the typo-free URL although npm start clearly shows the mistyped one.